# From where can i download gcc compiler fpr windows?? i m using vista OS

Tags: compiler-construction

please tell me a link for downloading the GCC compiler for C++. I m using windows vista as OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[mingw](http://www.mingw.org/)**

From the site:

> MinGW, a contraction of "Minimalist
>   GNU for Windows", is a port of the GNU
>   Compiler Collection (GCC), and GNU
>   Binutils, for use in the development
>   of native Microsoft Windows
>   applications.

Answer (score 2):

for the beginner, I would suggest [DevCPP](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html).

It comes bundled with the [mingw compiler](http://www.mingw.org/).

Answer (score 1):

And don't forget cygwin: http://cygwin.com/